# Active Storage: displaying video in video_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, rails-activestorage

In a Rails 5.2 app, I want to display a video previously uploaded in S3 via Active Storage. When I use this:

```
<%= video_tag [@banner_video.video_mp4, @banner_video.video_webm] %>
```

I get this error:

```
The asset "" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

I checked in console, and my variable @banner_video is exactly what I think it should be.

Comment: I guess your question is duplicate.Take a look at this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020753/the-asset-logo-png-is-not-present-in-the-asset-pipeline

Comment: No, the video is not in the asset pipeline, it's hosted on a remote S3 bucket. I displayed images with no pb.

Comment: Oh you are right.

Comment: @Ruff9 how ur uploading into cloud ? what do u use?

Comment: I did setup an ActiveAdmin interface, and a form with a file type field... my app is connected to my S3 bucket via Active Storage, and it works like a charm for images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution not using `video_tag`, with a little hack.

```
<video>
  <source src=<%= rails_blob_path(@banner_video.video_mp4) %> type="video/mp4" />
  <source src=<%= rails_blob_path(@banner_video.video_webm) %> type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

This is working, looks like `video_tag` is not handling remote sources.

Comment: In what might be considered vital if you don't know the content type, it's not necessary to render the video.

Comment: This works as well: <%= video_tag rails_blob_path(session.video) %>

Comment: Have you been able to play the video.  I can only have the preview appear, which is the first frame of the video only.  I want it to actually play...

Comment: <%= video_tag rails_blob_path(session.video), controls: true %>. **controls: true** make you able to preview.

Answer (score 3):

2 variants that I used to make it work

1. `<%= video_tag url_for(@banner_video.file), size: "150x120", controls: true %>`

or with to get S3 url

2. `<%= video_tag @banner_video.file.service_url, size: "150x120", controls: true %>`

Answer (score 2):

From [@Methaphysiker comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50993367/active-storage-displaying-video-in-video-tag#comment91634549_51002570):

```
<%= video_tag rails_blob_path(@banner_video.video_mp4) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

As said @metaphysiker 
This works as well: <%= video_tag rails_blob_path(session.video) %>